# Figlets installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, fonts, ascii-art

I have used figlet to create ASCII text for Source code comments. ([figlet website](http://www.figlet.org/)). Recently I upgraded to Windows 10. It used to work in Windows 7. (It is been few months since I used it though). But now it gives this error.

[image: figlet on windows 10]

How can I install figlet on windows 10, that allows me to generate figlet from command line, `figlet this is text`?

Comment: Windows has some built-in compatibility options. Right-click on a shortcut to figlet.exe to adjust these or try using the Compatibility Troubleshooter. Alternatively, have you contacted the Figlet developers to see if they have produced a 64-bit compatible version of the tool?

Comment: I tried to change the compatibility options, but it does not seem to work. Same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be late. But for the people who want to have `figlet` in windows.

`figlet` is 16 bit application. 64 bit windows has 32 bit window subsystem, but it doesn't support 16 bit. So there is no way you can run this application directly in 64 bit windows. But if you want to try it out you can run this program in a virtual machine.

If you can afford to install `nodejs`, then you can install `figlet-cli`.

```
npm install -g figlet-cli
```

It is not as light as `figlet`, but it can let the job done.

Comment: It works only with NodeJS command prompt. I would like it to be available for any windows command prompt, is that possible?

Comment: If you have installed it globally with -g flag. You can use it from normal command like any other program. But make sure that npm bin folder is in path. Most probably it will be %appdata%\npm.

Comment: It worked thank you. Accepted as an answer.